# How to get a smooth density curve over a discrete X axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a discrete x-axis with a small number of levels. I want a smooth curve showing the distribution. When I keep `gear` as a factor I get bars which is not exactly what I'm looking for, and when I use `gear` as a numeric I get jagged looking distribution which is not exactly what I am looking for either.

Does anyone have advice on showing a smooth distribution for discrete data?

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(gear), mpg)) +
  geom_density(stat = "identity")
```

[image: discrete_distribution]

Comment: What would a smooth density even mean when you have discrete values? There is no gear values that lie between 3 and 4. So why would you want to show data there? Do you want to look like there is anon-zero probability of having 3.25 gears? What do you want this curve to look like where your actual data doesn't have any support?

Comment: What I'm really try to say is that I want a persuasive way to show that number of people who have scores of " "very low", "low", "medium", "high", and "very high" levels hopefully without using a bar chart. You might be right that it is insincere to use a density curve, I'm just not sure of a better way :(

Comment: What's wrong with a bar chart? That's the most honest representation. The smoothing would be adding data where there simply is none with some additional modeling assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that this is potentially confusing or misleading, since connecting categorical variables implies a spectrum and a spacing that might be subjective or misleading.

But assuming it makes sense for your use case, you might approach this by converting your factors to numeric, continuous data "under the hood," and then adapting your labels back to a categorical type. For instance:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = as.factor(gear)) %>%
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  mutate(factor_num = as.numeric(gear)) -> temp

ggplot(temp, aes(x = factor_num, y = mpg)) +
  # This geom draws a smooth line through your points
  ggalt::geom_xspline(spline_shape = -0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = temp$factor_num, labels = temp$gear, name = "gear") +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]